# Find functions $f,g$ such that $f(x+y)=g(x·y)$ for all $x,y$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, functional-equations

My approach towards this question was that first I putted x=0 and then y=0 which yields f(x)=f(y)and f(x)=g(0), and again for x=1 & y=1 it gives g (x)=f(1+x), and so on. My query is that what should the compact & rigorous form of proof or solution looks like because I found myself stuck between results and not comprehending results very well. Thanks.

Comment: A friendly advice: [title should NOT be the first sentence of your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/356647). In particular, see the last bullet. Also, please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Okey thanks.I will remember next time.

Answer (score 7):

$$f(x) = f(x + 0) = g(x \cdot 0) = g(0)$$ for all $x$.  Thus $f(x)$ is constant and always equal to $g(0)$.  Moreover, $$g(0) = f(1 + y) = g(1 \cdot y) = g(y)$$ for all $y$.  Thus $g$ is also constant and equal to $g(0)$.  Thus $f, g$ are the same constant function.  All constant functions $f = g = c$ will satisfy the relation.  This is all you need.

Comment: Yeah thanks man m looking for this kind of preciseness.

Comment: Sorry I edited it because I made a mistake in description that g(x)=f(1+y) instead of g(x)=f(1+x).

Comment: Now I think your proof also needs editing?

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN where does it need edited?  I only used the relation f(x + y) = g(x y).

Comment: g(xy)=g(0) how?

Comment: in your answer g(0)=f(1+y) how?

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN because f is identically equal to g(0) as I show in the previous part.

Comment: ohk i.e identically equal means for any x in domain result is same?

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN yes that's what identically equal means

Comment: ohk thanks a lot.